# Custom shaped button in WPF won't display text block

Tags: wpf, xaml, .net-4.0

I'm attempting to create a button with a custom shape which I'm defining through `Path` and it works fine but I'm unable to make any button `Content` to show. I can see the button of a right shape and seemingly right behavior but `TextBlock` won't appear and I don't understand why.

This is a simple example of how I'm trying to do it. How can I make text to actually appar?

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1" x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="TestButton">
          <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
          <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
              <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">     
                <Path Data="M0.5,0.5 L99.500001,0.5 79.774476,97.648209 78.879563,97.219429 C70.748094,93.55407 61.630468,91.5 52.000001,91.5 41.299485,91.5 31.232103,94.035889 22.447118,98.50029 L22.394687,98.528488 z" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="99.028" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100">
                    <Path.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Path}">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="LightGray" />
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Black" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Path.Style>
                </Path>
                <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
                    </Style>
                </ControlTemplate.Resources>
            </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
        </Style>
</Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=TestButton}" Margin="154,80,-154,-80" >
            <TextBlock>Test</TextBlock>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: you want Test to be shown above or below the path?

Comment: @Nikita Actually I want it to be shown over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place  within your control template so that the TextBlock(content) can be shown :

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Button"> 
<Grid>   
<ContentPresenter/>
<Path ....../>
</Grid>
```

you can rearrange the path & content as if you please then.